# Android Application Architecture - Design Pattern

Tags: java, android, architecture

Need your valuable suggestions here. :)

I have to design an application which is almost similar to Zomato Application, i.e., it has various screens..the content is stored in the central server, and through the API the content is fetched and displayed on the screen.

What are generally the design /architectures used in Apps like zomato. 
How do we make apps that recover after going to the background/ Android Killing the state of the App?

Can you please let me know if you have had experience of having built any app similar to Zomato.

Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got what u really mean, you just need to recover info in onResume on activities and there's nothing specil about it. You should study activity lifeCycles and you'll be fine.